# OJDBC Error ORA-00922

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc

We have the problem, when we execute the following Statement in Java via OJDBC  we get

> Error Code ORA-00922: missing or invalid option.

When we run this directly to the Oracle database server, it works. Other create statements are working correctly. Why does it not work with OJDBC?

```
CREATE TABLE METADATA( 
     ID NUMBER(3) NOT NULL, 
     tableName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE ,  
     partitioningType NUMBER(3) NOT NULL ,  
     partitioning1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,  
     partitioning2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,  
     partitioning3 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,  
     restriction VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
     PRIMARY KEY (ID) );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remove the semicolon from the end of the statement.